# using QT process to get sensor information from the laptop using command line

Tags: c++, regex, string, qt, substring

I am using QT process to get information from lm-sensors library that I have installed and configured in my laptop.. I want to read the information from the command line and display it on my QT GUI, so that is what I am doing:

first when I use this command in the console, I get this output ..

```
$ sensors | grep "Core "
Core 0:         +51.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:         +49.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

and I want to parse this in my code .. so I do this

```
process->start("sensors | grep \"Core\"");
process->waitForReadyRead();
QByteArray strdata = process->readLine();
qDebug() << strdata;
```

and I get this in the output

```
"Try `sensors -h' for more information
```

and when I change the command line to

```
process->start("watch \"sensors | grep \"Core \"\"")
```

I get the output like above .. I tried different functions to get only the Core 0: +51 without the extra stuff..

I tried to use indexOf() function get the index and then parse it using a function like mid() .. NOt correct result .. then I tried and right() and left() function and they give me wrong output too!!!

any help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
process->start("sensors | grep \"Core\"");
```

The problem here is that the start function takes the first parameter as the program to execute and then passes subsequent parameters to the program as arguments, so the | grep and "Core" are being passed to the sensors command, which is then complaining because it doesn't know what to do with those arguments.

One way to solve this is to call sensors and get the returned information with readAllStandardOutput(). You can then either use the Qt string functions to search for the information you want, or if you set the standard output file with setStandardOutputFile, you can then call QProcess with grep on the that file. (Note QTemporaryFile may be of use here).

However, the simplest way would be to create a small command line script that calls your command

```
sensors | grep \"Core\"
```

then start a QProcess that calls your script.

Comment: I took the whole sensors output and parse it using indexOf() command .. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should try something like:

```
process->start("/bin/sh", "-c \"sensors | grep Core\");
```

The problem is:

`|` is part of `SHELL`, so shell runs first program and then runs second one.